# How to create 4 conditions out of two independent variables

Tags: spss

I have two independent variables with both two levels, which combined represent 4 conditions. I was wondering how I can the four different conditions out of the two independent variables so I can run a Pearson Chi-Square test and compare the 4 different conditions with for example age.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of ways to do this. The simplest version would be:

```
if conditionA=1 and conditionB=1 levelAB=1.
if conditionA=2 and conditionB=1 levelAB=2.
if conditionA=1 and conditionB=2 levelAB=3.
if conditionA=2 and conditionB=2 levelAB=4.
```

Here's another way you can go (assuming your condition variables are one digit numerics):

```
compute levelAB = 10 * conditionA + conditionB.
```

(of course in your syntax you'll have to replace the variable names and levels with the actual ones)